# tearing when plotting polygons with holes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, polygon

I'm trying to plot these body maps and can't get the face to show correctly. The "heads" are made up of two polygons: one is the face (solid oval) and the other is the rest of the head (donut-shaped, hole in the center). These should be colored based on the value of the "score" column. I've tried so many variations on where the **group=group** gets placed and the **fill=scale**.

[image: comparison of real data]

```
  ggplot(data=Patients, aes(y=lat, 
                            x=long, 
                            fill=factor(score), 
                            group=group))+
    geom_polygon(color="black")+
    facet_wrap(~Patient, 
               ncol = 5)+
    scale_fill_manual(values=scoreColor)+
    coord_fixed()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've included my attempt at a reproducible example below.

```
library(ggplot2)
fortifyResults <-read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, text="
                  long  lat order   hole    piece   group   id  score
                  1 1   1   FALSE   1   Outer.1 Outer   20
                  1 4   2   FALSE   1   Outer.1 Outer   20
                  4 4   3   FALSE   1   Outer.1 Outer   20
                  4 1   4   FALSE   1   Outer.1 Outer   20
                  1 1   5   FALSE   1   Outer.1 Outer   20
                  2 2   6   TRUE    2   Outer.2 Outer   20
                  3 2   7   TRUE    2   Outer.2 Outer   20
                  3 3   8   TRUE    2   Outer.2 Outer   20
                  2 3   9   TRUE    2   Outer.2 Outer   20
                  2 2   10  TRUE    2   Outer.2 Outer   20
                  2 2   11  FALSE   1   Inner.1 Inner   10
                  2 3   12  FALSE   1   Inner.1 Inner   10
                  3 3   13  FALSE   1   Inner.1 Inner   10
                  3 2   14  FALSE   1   Inner.1 Inner   10
                  2 2   15  FALSE   1   Inner.1 Inner   10
                  ")
```

This version of the code doesn't show both pieces (even though they are in the legend)

```
ggplot(data=fortifyResults, aes(y=lat, x=long, group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(score)),color="black")
```

And this one causes tearing

```
ggplot(data=fortifyResults, aes(y=lat, x=long), group=group)+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(score)),color="black")
```

[image: comparison of example]

I read that the direction of the points makes a difference. This is how the direction comes out.

```
ggplot(data= fortifyResults, aes(y=lat, x=long, group=group))+   
  geom_polygon(fill="yellow", color="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label=order),hjust=0, vjust=-0.3)+
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

Again, the one titled "outer" here should have a hole in the middle (hole==TRUE). From what I've read, they should go in the other direction. I've tried inverting the logic, changing the direction of the points, and a bunch of other stuff. I hope you folks can help.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, we now have `geom_polypath` from the `ggpolypath` package, which is designed precisely for this use case. See [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggpolypath/vignettes/ggpolypath.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggpolypath)

ggplot(data = fortifyResults, aes(y = lat, x = long, group = group)) +
    geom_polypath(aes(fill = factor(score)), color = "black")
```

[image: 1]